# How to recognize tapping on the whole oscillating SubView to perform interactive animation

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview, uitapgesturerecognizer

In the code below, the subview (cloud) oscillates on the location given.
On tapping that subview while oscillation, it moves out of the bounds to the right side, then moves in from the left.
But the tap gesture is not working on the whole subview, it works only on the right-side end of the oscillating subView.
I want slide out and in of cloud to work, whenever the whole subview of cloud is tapped.

Below is code of .h and .m file respectively.

File : OscillatingCloudsViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface OscillatingCloudsViewController : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet UIView *movingCloud1;
    UIImage *cldImg;
}

- (IBAction)animateCloud;
- (IBAction)animateCloudBegin;
@end
```

---

File : OscillatingCloudsViewController.m

```
#import "OscillatingCloudsViewController.h"

@implementation OscillatingCloudsViewController

- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapGestureAnimateCloud)];
    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    tapGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = YES;
    [movingCloud1 addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
    movingCloud1.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [super viewWillAppear:
     animated];

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self animateCloud]; 
}

- (IBAction) animateCloud
{
    cldImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cloud1.png"];
    movingCloud1=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, cldImg.size.width, cldImg.size.height)];
    [movingCloud1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:cldImg]];
    [self.view addSubview:movingCloud1];
    movingCloud1.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    [self viewWillAppear:YES];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];

    [UIView setAnimationDuration:5];
    [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:HUGE_VALF];
    [UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:YES];

    CGPoint pos = movingCloud1.center;
    pos.x = 220.0f;
    movingCloud1.center = pos;

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void) animateCloudHidden
{
    [movingCloud1 setHidden:YES];
}
- (IBAction)animateCloudBegin
{

        movingCloud1.frame = CGRectMake(-100, 50, cldImg.size.width, cldImg.size.height);
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];

        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
        [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:1];
        [UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:NO];

        CGPoint pos = movingCloud1.center;
        pos.x = cldImg.size.width;
        movingCloud1.center = pos;

        [UIView commitAnimations];

}

- (IBAction) tapGestureAnimateCloud
{  
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];

    [UIView setAnimationDuration:2];
    [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:1];
    [UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:NO];
    movingCloud1.center = CGPointMake(1100.0f, 81.5f);

    [UIView commitAnimations];

    [self performSelector:@selector(animateCloudBegin) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0f];
    [self performSelector:@selector(animateCloudHidden) withObject:nil afterDelay:3.0f];
    [self performSelector:@selector(animateCloud) withObject:nil afterDelay:3.0f];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

I have understood your problem. In viewwillApper you are assing the Gesture and in inside animateCloud method your allocating your movingCloud1 UIView.

For implementing this you need to fallow the bello steps.

- In ViewdidLoad you need to allocate and add the movingCloud1 view to you self.view.
- After add the Gesture to movingCloud1 view.
- Your tapGesture will work now. So inside your tapgesture method just  you need to set the animation for your movingCloud1 view